# Arrow functions in twig or craft cms

Tags: filter, filtering

I tried to use reduce function in template, but got error. It seems twig/craftcms can not work with such functions.
Reduce function docs: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/filters.html#reduce

My example:

```
{% set data = craft.entries.section("faqChannel").orderBy('faqOrder').all() %}
{% set types = data|reduce((acc, v) => v.faqType is not in acc ? acc|merge([v.faqType]) : acc, []) %}
```

Error:
`Twig Syntax Error – Twig_Error_Syntax`
`An opened parenthesis is not properly closed. Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "," ("punctuation" expected with value ")").`

Comment: This is likely a bug in Craft - can you share this on https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues so we can look into it?

Comment: @BradBell Done: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/4426

Answer (score 1):

Twig didn’t add arrow function support until v2.10.0, so you need to be on at least Craft 3.1.29 if you want to use them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use arrow functions everywhere, so you can assign them to variables for re-use, or pass them to Collection methods that support callbacks, you'll need Craft Closure:

https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-closure

More here: [Twig Arrow Functions](https://craftquest.io/courses/arrow-functions-in-twig)